# Test the css if we don’t have an iPad?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any means to test the css if we don't have an ipad?I tried this link
http://ipadpeek.com/ but didn't get the desired result

Comment: http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ is my favorite and BrowserStack.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try this site : [Mobile preview](http://preview.offermobi.com/preview/frames/)

Or this site: [Responsive Design Testing across Devices](http://www.browserstack.com/responsive)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Canary has this built in, a mobile emulator:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

http://techcrunch.com/2013/12/03/chrome-beta-gets-new-tools-for-mobile-development-with-better-viewport-emulation-screencast-enabled-remote-debugging/

It allows you to emulate a whole lot of devices, including iPad 1 up to 4 including iPad Mini.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

http://browserstack.com

There are a list of different browsers and platforms, and iPad too.

if you use macos, there is a good emulator of iPad and iPhone inside XCode